# Connecting to ArcGIS ImageServer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, image-service

I'm having trouble opening an ArcGIS ImageServer layer in QGIS. The city of Fort Worth, TX has a 2017 ortho imagery service which can be opened in ArcGIS. I've tried to connect to it as a WMS Layer and as an ArcGIS MapServer Layer through QGIS, both of which prompt a bad request error message.

This is the link that shows in the ArcGIS layer properties:

https://mapit.fortworthtexas.gov/ags/rest/services/Imagery/Orthos_2017/ImageServer

Comment: Perhaps review these Q&As: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bimage-service%5d%20qgis

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same issue with a Loudoun County, VA ImageService for 2017 orthographic satellite imagery:

https://logis.loudoun.gov/image/rest/services/Aerial/COLOR_2017/ImageServer

I partially overcame this issue by accessing their Imagery folder as opposed to their Aerial folder. Their imagery folder came with a WMTS link, which works with "Add WMS/WMTS Layer", but the projection is off and I cannot seem to reproject it properly. I doubt it is an issue with the county's data and I presume it is a limitation inside of QGIS that is preventing me from solving this issue. I noticed your server has a WMTS option for the 2015 imagery, which may provide you a less than optimal workaround. Hopefully you don't have the same issue as me, where projections are concerned.

Answer (score 3):

Hey i found this plugin to be useful:  https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ImageServerConnector/

Comment: Thank you is this still working for you? Trying to connect to
https://historical1.arcgis.com/arcgis/services/USA_Historical_Topo_Maps/ImageServer